# Sci-fi youth novel with a young female protagonist who is watching over the development of another planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, space-colonization

It's a lovely romantic youth novel that I read many years ago in German. It's about a girl who is part of a crew that is observing the development of other planets. They are from a very well-evolved planet and developed psychic powers already.

The idea is that all planets go through similar points of development. They observe a planet that is in the Middle Ages, but at the same time being colonised by another planet that is in a planetary colonialisation phase. So against her agenda, the protagonist is starting to help the planet defend itself against the industrial civilisation that is trying to conquer it.

She disguises her telekinetic powers as magic, meets a guy who she falls in love with, and together they try to stop the colonisation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 13):

This sounds very much like [Enchantress from the Stars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137223/story-with-multiple-third-planet-races) by [Sylvia Engdahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_Engdahl).

There is a [summary here](https://www.supersummary.com/enchantress-from-the-stars/summary/), such as:

> Written in 1970 by Sylvia Louise Engdahl, Enchantress from the Stars
> is a young adult science fiction novel about Elana, a teenage girl
> from an advanced civilization, who faces conflicts between her heart
> and her duty when she poses as a magical sorceress in order to aid a
> young civilization against an invading empire.

Comment: The first link is to an accepted answer identifying the same book, so if this is accepted we can mark it duplicate (not a bad thing!)

Comment: Oh wow that was quick. Yes it actually is that book. Thank you so much, i was looking for this book for years and it got me crazy when ever I thought of it, that i just couldn t find it. This is so awesome, thank you so much :D

Comment: @Paul you can mark this answer as Accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.